# Watch multiple server Processor usage?

Tags: windows-server-2003, memory-usage, central-processing-unit

I am looking for a tool or easy way to watch the processor/memory usage on multiple Windows 2003 servers. We suspect an App is making it use 100% processor because of large memory usuage  and want to confirm by monitoring it. Although it doesn't happen all the time only when we have a higher traffic. Any Recommendations?

Answer (score 1):

Perfmon is great for real-time point-in-time monitoring of this sort of thing. An SNMP collector is a better tool for long-term trending, but if you're trying to solve a problem as it's happening, fire up your Perfmon and go to town.

Also - there's no reason to assume that large RAM usage will automatically correlate with 100% CPU usage. They're independent of each other - although for a given application, they may both be correlated to a single root cause like increased user load or bad queries. I'm sure you'll find that out as you investigate, but don't assume something like that, you'll waste time looking for it.

Comment: stay away from snmp on windows for performance monitoring.  use the native WMI monitoring available.  I would disagree that snmp is a viabel or reliable tool for long term monitoring on windows.  Monitor with both and you should notice differences between the 2 (with WMI being the correct values)

Comment: @Jim - Do you have any sources that you could cite?

Comment: By that, I don't mean to say you're wrong; I'd like to get more details. I do see that Nagios uses an agent to monitor Windows; Zenoss uses software called SNMP informant that queries Windows performance via WMI and then translates that into SNMP. So, that's some evidence that could back what you're claiming. I'd just like to see some serious documentation getting into the weeds of this claim.

Comment: I don't know of any documentation that explicitly states SNMP is wrong, I'm going by my experience with using them both, in the past I've had to refute the SNMP data by showing them that the WMI data  (comparing both the raw counters and polled wmi counters) for items like CPU utilization, memory and disk.  Try it and see what you get, I've never seen them line up but maybe it's just my bad luck

Comment: Cool, good to know.